# javafx vbox and gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

**Problem:**
I have a confusion in between vbox and gridpane.. Usually when you could use vbox, you could as well use gridPane of 1 column and n rows, so I am and not sure when to use each and the difference.

**Facts:**

- I know that a gridpane has n rows and n columns.
- I know that vbox would only list components vertically. (n rows 1 column)

**Confusion:** It comes when say I want to list 40-50 (horizontal boxes or other components) vertically, I don't know which of them to pick cause sometimes I see people adding those components into a vbox as children, and others would use gridpane n(rows)x1(column) and would always create a row constraint dynamically.

**Further more:**
In java swing, I would use gridBagLayout cause in my case it was the only layout to benefit from the constraint feature since those components are of different heights. However, in javafx, I can still put components of different sizes in a vbox as well **or** use the gridPane which is the alternative of gridbaglayout in java swing.

**Summary:**

In swing gridbaglayout is the only solution, in javafx vbox or gridpane(alternative to gridbaglayout in swing)?

**------ Edit ------**

When I put my hbox inside a gridpane cell, the components inside the box resize, however, they don't when I put the hbox inside a vbox.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="1080.0" maxWidth="1920.0" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER">
         <content>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="350.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="250.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="label">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField />
                        <ImageView fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="" />
                           </image>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets right="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="350.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="250.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="another label">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField />
                        <ImageView fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="" />
                           </image>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets right="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Why aren't the components resizing accordingly to the current size of the hbox?

Comment: If you're displaying 40-50+ rows of items, you may also want to consider using a `ListView`.

Comment: @Slaw vbox is not ideal if they are above 40-50? Also, may you look at my edit on the question please?

Comment: Depends on how complex the UI is. A `VBox` (and `GridPane`) will have to perform computations for all its children, regardless of if they end up is the visual area or not. This can get expensive and harm performance. A `ListView`, on the other hand, is a virtualized control, which means it only renders as many cells as can be seen. Of course, it may be non-trivial to replace a `GridPane`-based layout with a `ListView`.

Comment: What do you want to resize when a hbox changes size?  The width of the TextField in it? To do so, set a resize priority attribute on the text field, `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"`.  Note: because you have constraints on your hbox (minwidth 250 and maxwidth 350), and some elements already have a preferred width beyond 350, the resize priority isn't going to do a whole lot.  If this is not what you want, then you will need to do a better job of describing exactly what your requirements are and what isn't working.

Comment: Also, you have everything wrapped in a ScrollPane with `hbarPolicy="NEVER"`, so, if you make the width not very wide, the stuff in the scroll pane will just get clipped and you won't be able to scroll horizontally to see it.

Comment: @Slaw Aha got it, thanks! However, I am using components of different sizes, so I have to stick with a vbox :/

Comment: ListView can handle components of different sizes.

Comment: Perhaps one thing you want to do is set `fitToWidth="true"` attribute on your scrollpane, so that it will resize the content inside according to the display width (without scrolling) available to the scrollpane.

Comment: @jewelsea yeah, I know I don't want there to be a horizontal scrollbar. And I would like all the components within the hbox to resize accordingly based on the given size. Here is how it looks when I put the hbox in a gridpane column https://gyazo.com/b650fe5b530d9b980f0556f725d18821 and would like to have similar approach with the vbox applied.

Comment: I think setting resize priority on the elements in the hbox and setting fit constraints on the scrollpane will achieve what you want, please try it.

Comment: aha fitToWidth="true" seems to have fixed it. Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: Setting the priorty in Scene Builder, click on an element in the HBox, go to "Layout", change the "Hgrow" value in "HBox constraints". OR in FXML set HBox.hgrow attribute on the element OR in Java call [`HBox.setHGrow(node, priority)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.scene.layout.Priority))

Comment: I think fabian answered your original question well, please mark that correct.  The resizing and scrolling stuff discussed in the edit and comments is a different question (best to ask such things as new questions in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VBox`, unless you need features only provided by `GridPane`. There are less layout parameters to specify for `VBox` which makes it easier to use and reduces the potential sources of errors. Furthermore it's more expensive to do the layout with `GridPane` which could slow down updates for applications changing the size of the node often.

There are things you cannot achieve using `VBox` though (at least not in a convenient way):

- Placing multiple children in the same "cell" (could be done by wrapping those children in another layout)
- `rowSpan`
- specify the relative size of "rows" (could be done by binding the `prefHeight` properties of children, but it's more clean using `GridPane`)
- alignment of children in "cells"
- leaving "cells" empty (could be done applying a margin, but this gets complicated for relative heights)
- ...